# expansion of a root of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How may I find an expansion of the terms

$$(x+x^2)^\alpha $$
for $
0<\alpha<1/2$?
I would like to show that the linear term dominates the first one. I would like to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+x^2)^\alpha -x = -\infty$$?

Comment: This question has many issues. For first, the title: no roots of polynomials seem to be involved here. For second: how can we show that a certain term of an expansion is big or small without using an expansion? For third: what is the meaning of $\sum_{|\beta|\leq\alpha}x^{1-\beta}$, since $\alpha$ is a real number?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $(x+x^2)^\alpha $ is a root of the polynomial $x+x^2$ for this range of $\alpha$.

Comment: Still makes no sense to me: $x+x^2$ has only two roots: $0$ and $-1$.

Comment: By root I mean n-th root for $\alpha=1/n$.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem)